# How to calculate the mean of a column dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I have this dataframe and i want to calculate the Temperature mean for each day:

```
       Dates       Temp
13     2019-08-02  24.5
20     2019-08-02  24.3
27     2019-08-03  24.1
34     2019-08-03  23.7
41     2019-08-04  23.6
```

I use this code that seemed good to me:

```
df.groupby('Dates', as_index=False)['Temp'].mean()
```

But the final result is this, which is clearly not the good output as i would have the mean temperature for each day of the year :

```
        Dates  Temp
0  2019-08-02  24.4
1  2019-08-03  23.9
2  2019-08-04  23.6
```

Any idea?

Comment: I updated your output with the real result of the command, please be specific and provide a fully reproducible example as code if this is not what you get

Answer (score 1):

If data has same year use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

y = df['Dates'].dt.year.min()
r = pd.date_range(f'{y}-01-01', f'{y}-12-31', name='Dates')
df1 = df.groupby('Dates')['Temp'].mean().reindex(r).reset_index()
print (df1)
         Dates  Temp
0   2019-01-01   NaN
1   2019-01-02   NaN
2   2019-01-03   NaN
3   2019-01-04   NaN
4   2019-01-05   NaN
..         ...   ...
360 2019-12-27   NaN
361 2019-12-28   NaN
362 2019-12-29   NaN
363 2019-12-30   NaN
364 2019-12-31   NaN

[365 rows x 2 columns]
```

If multiple years:

```
y1, y2 = df['Dates'].dt.year.min(), df['Dates'].dt.year.max()
r = pd.date_range(f'{y1}-01-01', f'{y2}-12-31')
df.groupby('Dates')['Temp'].mean().reindex(r).reset_index()
```